# Laravel jQuery ui autocomplete doesn't showing response data properly

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, laravel-5

I have tried to implement a auto complete search system in my laravel app. I have stored all the css and js file correctly. Now, when I type something which matches with the specified field of database, some little boxes is appearing without any text inside. What is the problem? Why can I not pass the response data to the view?

Here is my controller.

```
public function autocomplete(Request $request){
      $term=$request->term;
      $data=User::where('name','LIKE','%'.$term.'%')->take(10)->get();
      $result=array();
      foreach($data as $key=>$user){
       $result[]=['name'=>$user->name];

      }

      return response()->json($result);
    }
```

Here is my view.

```
<?php include "/Assests_PHP/JS.php";?>
<?php include "/Assests_PHP/CSS.php";?>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0-beta.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
<section class="panel panel-default">
<header class="panel-heading">
<input type="text" name="name" id="searchname" class="form-control" placeholder="search user"/>

</header>
<div class="panel-body">

</div>
</section>
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#searchname').autocomplete({
  source:'{!!URL::route('autocomplete')!!}',
   minlength:1,
  autoFocus:true,
  select:function(e,ui){

    alert(ui);
  }

});
```

Answer (score -1):

> what is the problem

Your object structure doesn't match the expected defaults per the autocomplete ***Source*** docs

> Array: An array can be used for local data. There are two supported
>   formats:
>
> ```
> An array of strings: [ "Choice1", "Choice2" ]
> An array of objects with label and value properties: [ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]
> ```
>
> The label property is displayed in the suggestion menu. The value will
>   be inserted into the input element when a user selects an item. If
>   just one property is specified, it will be used for both, e.g., if you
>   provide only value properties, the value will also be used as the
>   label.